# My calculator buttons don't seem to be connecting to my javascript. The console isn't giving me any errors

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buttons on my calculator don't seem to be working and i believe i linked everything correctly. Maybe im missing something so any help would be greatly appreciated. Maybe a fresh set of eyes will be able to notice where i went wrong and can point it out. I'm still new to javascript.I tried checking to see if it's due to the previous operand and current operand but i still see nothing about it

```js
class Calculator {
  constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
    this.clear()
  }


  clear() {
    this.currentOperand = ''
    this.previousOperand = ''
    this.operation = undefined
  }

  delete() {

  }

  appendNumber(number) {
    if (number === '.' && this.currentOperand.uncludes('.')) return
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString()
  }

  chooseOperation(operation) {

  }

  compute() {

  }

  updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand
  }

}
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
const allclearButton = document.querySelectorAll('[data-all-clear]')
const deleteButton = document.querySelectorAll('[data-delete]')
const operationButton = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
const equalsButton = document.querySelectorAll('[data-equals]')
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelectorAll('[previous-operand]')
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelectorAll('[current-operand]')

const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)

numberButtons.forEach(button => {

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Calculater</title>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="calculator-grid">
    <div class="output">
      <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div>
      <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
    </div>
    <button data-all-clear class="span-two">AC</button>
    <button data-delete>DEL</button>
    <button data-number>1</button>
    <button data-number>2</button>
    <button data number>3</button>
    <button data-number>4</button>
    <button data-number>5</button>
    <button data-number>6</button>
    <button data-number>7</button>
    <button data-number>8</button>
    <button data-number>9</button>
    <button data-operation>÷</button>
    <button data-operation>*</button>
    <button data-operation>+</button>
    <button data-operation>-</button>
    <button data-operation>.</button>
    <button data-number>0</button>
    <button data-equals class="span-two">=</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The JavaScript needs to be in a `<script>` tag

Comment: this.currentOperand.uncludes - should that be includes? I don't think uncludes is right...also, check your dev console for js errors.

Comment: You're setting `currentOperandTextElement` to a list of nodes, not a single node. Setting its `innerText` doesn't do anything. Use `querySelector` when you only want one element.